# How to force Entity Framework 6 to drop/create table instead of renaming?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project with EF6/CodeFirst setup. I'm having a scenario where I want to introduce polymorphism in the following way:

Was:

```
[T]
```

I want to be

```
     [BaseT]
    /       \
 [OutT]     [InT] <-- former [T]
```

However, since I'm in the design phase, I don't care about T and I'm happy to drop it and create a new hierarchy from scratch instead of renaming T to InT and attempting to glue everything together.

EF6, asked to create a new migration, consistently tries to rename T to InT, what causes a lot of problems with relations.

Is there a way to tell EF6 to drop the table and create new ones instead of attempting to rename it?

If not, how can I achieve that by manipulating entity contents? Is renaming entity, its table in attribute and e.g. adding a dummy field enough for EF to see it as a different entity?

Comment: Can't you just start with one new migration?